# DNN serves "fresh" pages to crawlers. How do I make it serve cached pages to crawlers?

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

Serving uncached ("fresh") pages to crawlers like Googlebot is a default DNN behavior, according to DNN. Many of our website's pages are heavy and we utilize DB caching extensively.

What setting can I tweak to serve cached pages to crawlers? I could not find anything in web.config or rules.config that seemed related to that. Is it something I need to add?

I found no documentation googling for it. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the DNN Platform that serves content differently to crawlers than that of regular visitors to the site, so they should be seeing the same thing that the rest see.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. I was citing this page, bullet point #2: https://support.managed.com/kb/a2374/how-to-utilize-dnn-page-output-caching.aspx "Search engine crawlers will receive a fresh copy of a page, every time they visit. This is so they get the most up to date information for your website." Just realized it wasn't DNN's website :)

Comment: Yeah that article is a little bit misleading, as you have to enable that feature, and many other criteria, plus it isn't doing browser detection anymore.